# Fetch duplicate records as well as Unique record in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have table mentioned below (id and Loc are Primary Keys)

```
ID  LOC RNK NBR1 NBR2 
1   2   A   10   b --->
3   4   A   10   b --->
5   6   A   11   C
8   2   A   12   D
6   3   A   10   b --->
```

SO here I have to fetch only duplicate records according to NBR1 and NBR2, It should fetch all the records not only the duplicates(marked as --->).

Comment: Do you want ALL records or only the duplicates? I don't understand..

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I want only id no 1,3,6.

Comment: I tried the Dens_rank and also the count but not able to fetch all the duplicate records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can do it with a subquery

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int, LOC int, RNK char(1), NBR1 int, NBR2 char(1) )

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES
    (1, 2, 'A', 10, 'b'),
    (3, 4, 'A', 10, 'b'),
    (5, 6, 'A', 11, 'C'),
    (8, 2, 'A', 12, 'D'),
    (6, 3, 'A', 10, 'b')

SELECT *
FROM #Test t1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM #Test t2
     WHERE t1.NBR1 = t2.NBR1
       AND t1.NBR2 = t2.NBR2
     GROUP BY NBR1, NBR2
     HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```

Comment: Here I want all the records..If I used the count and from this example I get the output likeID  LOC RNK NBR1 NBR2 
1   2   A   10   b --->1
3   4   A   10   b --->2
5   6   A   11   C -->1
8   2   A   12   D -->1
6   3   A   10   b --->3  so I want the duplicate records which I marked as 1,2,3 and kick of the unique ones.

Comment: so I want the duplicate records which I marked as 1,2,3 and kick of the unique ones.

Comment: Let me try...but Its filtering the count >1 but I want the all duplicate count from 1,2,3 ...

Comment: @Kenneth- I wrote your answer with my actual table columns but It takes lots of time, I have more than 6 million Records in this table.Do you have any other option to perform this functionality.

Comment: Do you have an index on NBR1 & NBR2?  The problem is that no matter what you do you are going to have to find the duplicates and with 6 million rows that takes time.  That index should make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this, but cost will be more. The RowsCount having values greater than 1 are duplicate and having values 1 are unique records.

```
With Temp As
(
    Select ID,LOC,RNK,NBR1,NBR2,Row_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NBR2 ORDER BY NBR1) AS ROWSCOUNT FROM <<TABLE_NAME>>
)

Select * from Temp
```